# відповідно до відчуттів

Tags: вибір-слова

Наприклад, я травмував ногу і приходжу до лікаря, питаю: "Чи маю я переважно лежати, обмежити рух?" А він відповідає: "Відповідно до відчуттів". Можна так? Чи як краще?

Comment: залежно від самопочуття.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У «Гуглі» я бачу:

- [«відповідно до відчуттів»](https://google.com?q=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%B4%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%87%D1%83%D1%82%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%22) — десятки траплянь, зокрема:

  > Зробіть 5-10 разів, корегуючи темп та кількість відповідно до відчуттів… // Панченко Марина Григорівна, методичні рекомендації 
  >   «Формування комунікативної компетенції вихованців ПНЗ Київщини засобами театрального мистецтва», Біла Церква, 2016.
- [«за відчуттями»](https://google.com?q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%87%D1%83%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%22) — сотні траплянь і десятки книжок, щоправда серед них багато в інших значеннях, але є й у потрібних, зокрема:

  > За відчуттями вона була не з хромованої сталі… // Stephen King, «Christine», у перекладі Олени Любенко, Харків, «Клуб сімейного дозвілля», 2017.
- [«згідно з відчуттями»](https://google.com?q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%B7+%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%87%D1%83%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%22) — десятки траплянь, зокрема:

  > Адекватність анестезії визначалась самооцінкою пацієнта відповідно до горизонтальної десятисантиметрової візуальної аналогової шкали (ВАШ), на якій 0 мм репрезентував відсутність болю, 100 мм — нестерпний біль згідно з відчуттями пацієнта, та словесної рейтингової шкали (СРШ). // Світлик Ю. О., стаття «Особливості впливу лідокаїну, ропівакаїну та бупівакаїну, введених епідурально, на ритм та провідність серця» в журналі «Медицина склданих станів» за № 5 (68), 2015.

Особисто я не бачу, чому якийсь із цих варіантів міг би бути неможливим. Хіба що «від… до від…» звучить не дуже приємно (повтор), але семантично, по-моєму, усе гаразд.